# How to show the labels using Interactive legend plugin on mpld3?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, mpld3

I am following the code shown [here](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/interactive_legend.html) to show the results of an experiment. However, I can't manage to show the labels, the interactivity works but still is not showing the labels. Here I send the labels to the plugin, but I don't know if I am missing some boolean parameter to allow the labels to be shown.

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() # return lines and labels
interactive_legend = plugins.InteractiveLegendPlugin(zip(handles, ax.collections),
                                                     labels,
                                                     alpha_unsel=0,
                                                     alpha_over=0, 
                                                     start_visible=True)
plugins.connect(fig, interactive_legend)
```

Any idea very appreciated it.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of labels not being shown with the InteractiveLegendPlugin is even present on the [official example](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/interactive_legend.html).

The reason may be better observed when changing the background color of the plot: The **legend labels are cut off by the figure edge**.

[image]

The solution is therefore to use a larger margin on the right side of the figure, such that the labels are within the figure edges. This can e.g. be done via

```
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally  I ended up using this code that creates a box in the bottom with the labels, making it look very organized:

`plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
           fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)`

[image: Labels in a box]